# How to get Treeview's selected node's path as a treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview. And i want to get the selected(clicked) node's path as a treeview again.
Is there any solution?
Example treeview;

```
.node1
   .node1.1
   .node1.2
.node2
   .node2.1
   .node2.2
   .node2.3
       .node2.3.1
       .node2.3.2
```

when i click node2.3.2 than i want to get such a result:

```
node2
   node2.3
       node2.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean create another TreeView with the selected node as the root, then you'd clone the node, create a TreeView and then add the cloned node. I have a strange feeling that's not what you mean though....

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
TreeView ConvertTreeNodeToTreeView(TreeNode tn) {
        TreeView tv = new TreeView();
        tv.Nodes.Add(tn);
        return tv;
    }

    protected void tv_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.tv.SelectedNode != null) {
            this.Panel1.Controls.Add(ConvertTreeNodeToTreeView(tv.SelectedNode));
        }
    }
```